# My PostgreSQL calculations don't include decimals

Tags: sql, decimal

I don't dabble in SQL queries much and rely on google when I need something more than the basics, and have come up with a problem.

I am trying to calculate a value and it returns a result rounded down to the nearest integer.

To test this out, I wrote the following query:

```
select ELAPTIME AS "ELAPSEC", ELAPTIME/60 AS "ELAPMIN" from CMR_RUNINF
```

The result is:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|ELAPSEC    |ELAPMIN    |
+-----------+-----------+
|258        |4          |
+-----------+-----------+
|0          |0          |
+-----------+-----------+
|2128       |35         |
+-----------+-----------+
|59         |0          |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to do a bit more than this, but I've simplified it to make it easier to explain the problem. How do I ensure that this calculation returns the decimal point?

Comment: Providing syntax of SQL Server, Cast(ELAPTIME as Float)/60. In short convert your variable first,before dividing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL product performs integral division because both operands are integers. `ELAPTIME`'s integer type is determined be the table structure and `60` is automatically assumed to be integer because it has no decimal point.

There are two methods of resolving the issue:

1. Convert either operand to a non-integer numeric type explicitly:

   ```
   CAST(ELAPTIME AS float) / 60
   ```
2. Write `60.0` instead of `60` so that the parser can see you are not dividing an integer by an integer:

   ```
   ELAPTIME / 60.0
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
postgres=# SELECT 258/60::float;
 ?column? 
----------
      4.3
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I went with the other option, but it's good to know all the options.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
SELECT ELAPTIME AS "ELAPSEC", ELAPTIME/60 :: Float AS "ELAPMIN" 
FROM CMR_RUNINF
```

Or:

```
SELECT ELAPTIME AS "ELAPSEC", ELAPTIME/60 :: Real AS "ELAPMIN" 
FROM CMR_RUNINF
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/d41d8/202)**